# How to show the configuration of my CMake?

Tags: configuration, cmake

I'm looking for a command like `cmake --features` or `cmake --config` which shows me how my CMake executable was built. For example, I want to know weather the flags like `--system-bzip2` really did get used and check the paths to the libraries CMake uses.

I am not interested in knowing what features are available on which CMake version, but which options were actually used in the build.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please clarify: do we really talk about the `cmake` executable itself or about a project generated by CMake?

Comment: @Florian : I edited my question

Comment: Thanks @usr1234567 this will (have to) do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find out, which libraries are used for the compiling of your CMake executable, I see three ways, as there is no `--feature` or `--config` provided by CMake.

1. Check the output of CMake's configure run. For most libraries, it indicates the path to the library.
2. Check the `CMakeCache.txt` within the build directory. You can find out the library paths
3. When you build CMake, call `make VERBOSE=ON` and check the output.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's no such a feature in the CMake executable.
You should check your CMake version toward the official documentation to check whether a given feature is included in that version.
There's a nice tool, written in CMake language, that automates this work, you can find more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40844358/finding-which-cmake-version-a-feature-was-introduced-in).

Comment: You know, there is a reason why Florian and I answered in the comments but not (yet) as an answer.

Comment: @ usr1234567 It would be nice to know what the reason is, thank you. I could delete my answer then.

Comment: For example, the question was not clear. Your answer does not match the edited question. And I dislike your fasted-gun-in-west style, cf. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem

Comment: It was clear enough to me, otherwise I would not have answered, right? About your other opinion, well, ok, it's your opinion, and I'm sure the SO mechanisms should take care of this kind of situations. I appreciate your commenting back, thank you.